# How can I add a new Windows 10 into grub, and have grub act as my primary bootloader?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, ssd

I currently have three different Storage Devices: 1 NVMe SSD that (by definition) is on my motherboard, and 2 SSDs connected by two different SATA cables to my motherboard.

I would like to install Windows 10 on the NVMe, Ubuntu on one of the two SSDs, and another copy of Windows 10 on the other of the two SSDs.

I would like to know if it is possible that, after installing everything, I can be greeted by a grub screen that asks which OS I want to load into, and it displays my three options, and I click on the operating system of my choosing to be instantly loaded into it.

I ask because I have tried, and failed, to do this. I installed Windows 10 on the NVMe, then Windows 10 on one internal SSD, then Ubuntu on the other, but I keep being greeted by a Windows screen asking me to choose a SSD to load Windows from.

-- Personal Note
I would appreciate an easy step-by-step if it exists. I am debugging-exhausted. Lost all of my data on my phone and computer, tried to recover them for a week straight and nothing. I would really, really love something that is clear and will carry me through without much difficulty, *if it exists*. Thanks for anything regardless

Comment: Windows always combines boot into one ESP (or back with old BIOS one boot partition) and then BCD has the multiple boot choice. You need to partition in advance with gpt partitioning & ESP on every drive. Then either disconnect other drives or in UEFI settings disable drives. You may be able to temporarily remove ESP flags, so other drives not seen as bootable. Grub only boots working Windows and even Windows may have issues if one Windows sets hibernation & other is not. So make sure Windows fast start up is off.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: set your UEFI to boot Ubuntu as the first-priority boot option.

Step 2: run `sudo update-grub` inside Ubuntu. It should automatically detect the Windows installs and add them as Grub entries.

Comment: Thank you. This looks very clear. When I get back home from work ill try this.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't pick up my Windows 10 install on my NVMe